# How to secure django powered site on IIS 8.0

Tags: python, django, iis-8

I have setup a django site using Helicon Zoo with IIS 8.0 on Windows Server 2012. My site includes the /admin, and I want secure only the admin with HTTPS. I have been searching on the Web for a while, but still cannot figure out how to do it.

I did find out some solution for Apache, Nginx, etc. [e.g., http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2009/02/18/securing-django-with-ssl/], but NOT IIS 8.0.

Comment: If you are going to the trouble to set up TLS why not use it for the entire site? There is really no good reason to *not* so so.

Comment: My current situation does not allow me to buy a certificate. If I force to use TLS, the browser of other (external) users will complain the insecure certificate, although the internal users like me feels ok with it.

Comment: Just some history lesson for future readers. HTTPS is a setting that only applies to IIS sites, so you need to enable HTTPS on the entire site even if you want to secure just `/admin`. The actual steps to enable HTTPS on an IIS site can be easily found everywhere. Besides, use HttpPlatformHandler for your Django site on IIS https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/